# WPF: Set background color of cells of a particular column based on column index in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set the background color of all the cells of a particular column in WPF Datagrid.

The requirement is pretty straight forward and simple but I am pretty new to WPF.

I found hundred of posts like this [Style Only One Column's Cells DataGrid C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942806/style-only-one-columns-cells-datagrid-c-sharp-wpf) which are using `DataGridCell` and `DataTrigger` combination to set style of a particular cell, but the trigger is always dependent on data on that cell, while I do not want to depend on data but just the column index.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a simple Style with one setter for Background (individual style for each column):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ...}" Header="Red">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ...}" Header="Green">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ...}" Header="Blue">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I wanted. I knew it would be very simple but since I am new to WPF so I am struggling.
Is there any way to define the common css style to reuse it if I want to use the same background color for multiple columns?

Comment: There is no column index in this answer

Comment: @Orace - But it does make the change of all the cells of a particular column, which was I wanted.

Comment: So this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416831

Comment: @Orace - I one sense, yes. In another sense, no. Because in that post this part of the solution `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">` is checking the value of the column data to style the column cell

Comment: The questions are the same "how to set cell styles by column", you wish for background color, on the other question OP wished for background color when selected. If I open a question about setting the font size in one column it's not a duplicate?